# R Shinyapp works locally but not on Shinyapp.io server

Tags: r, rcharts, shiny

I am trying to make a shinyapp which let users upload a certain format of file. After uploading the file, the shinyapp will automatically plot some table and charts using dplyr and rCharts.

It works well when I run it locally using “Run App”. However, when I publish to shinyapp.io, I got this error:

**path[1](https://github.com/johnnychiuchiu/Cheetah_ShinyApp/blob/master/server.r)="": No such file or directory**

After searching on the internet, I haven’t found any solution to solve this problem. Could anyone help me on what the possible reason causing this issue?

Here is my code and my sessionInfo().(It's a little bit long and messy)
https://github.com/johnnychiuchiu/Cheetah_ShinyApp/blob/master/server.r

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.4 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_1.0.0 dplyr_0.4.2   rCharts_0.4.5 shiny_0.12.2 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.1       lattice_0.20-33   assertthat_0.1   
[4] digest_0.6.8      mime_0.3          grid_3.2.2       
[7] plyr_1.8.3        R6_2.1.0          DBI_0.3.1        
[10] xtable_1.7-4      jsonlite_0.9.16   magrittr_1.5     
[13] stringi_0.5-5     lazyeval_0.1.10   rstudioapi_0.3.1 
[16] whisker_0.3-2     RJSONIO_1.3-0     tools_3.2.2      
[19] parallel_3.2.2    httpuv_1.3.3      yaml_2.1.13      
[22] rsconnect_0.4.1.4 htmltools_0.2.6
```

Comment: You've shared a huge script and haven't said where exactly it's failing, but from the error message it looks like your app is looking for a file that's local to your environment but not to the Shiny server. I think you need to put the stored data in a path that the Shiny server can see.

Comment: @ulfelder thanks so much for the reply. I am sorry for sharing my messy code.

I think I don't understand how come the file is not on shiny server after I upload the file in shinyapp.io. 

The file upload related code is refer to [File upload example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "h" in "Highcharts" needs to be lowercase, e.g.:

```
showOutput("h5", "highcharts"),
```

If that doesn't work: For the deployment, showOutput needs you to detail the path to your rcharts-lilbrary (at least in my case, for whatever reason ^^).

I had a problem which was very similar to yours. Here's my solution: 
["ERROR: path[1]="": No such file or directory" when publishing Parallel Coordinates Chart with Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36691327/error-path1-no-such-file-or-directory-when-publishing-parallel-coordina)